# More elegant way of transforming data frames from wide to long data fromat by using reshape() or melt()

Tags: r, reshape

I am looking for a more elegant way of reshaping my data frame by using the melt (reshape2) or reshape function.

Let’s assume I have a simple data frame like this:

```
d<-data.frame("PID"=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)),
              "Cue1"=factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3)),
              "Cue2"=factor(c(5,5,5,5,5,5)))
```

And I would like to transform the second and third columns to a single long one. My code below works but I am looking for a more elegant way:

```
d1<-data.frame("trigger"=as.vector(t(d[,c(2:3)])))
d1$PID<-factor(rep(c(1,2),each=6))
```

It is important that the number of levels of the two factors are different (Cue1 has 3, Cue2 has 1 level). My code above gives me the new column that looks like this (this is actually what I want):

```
trigger
1
5
2
5
3
5
...
```

Unfortunately, most of the examples on the internet about reshape discusses the following (and in my case, non-preferred) example:

```
trigger
1
2
3
1
2
3
...
```

But I need the former one.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by elegant? In terms of compactness? Don't think any variants will be significantly shorter than what you've done.

Comment: In my solution, I have to add a new column for PID, plus another one for identifying whether a value in the column comes from cue1 or 2 (not shown in the above example). I thought there is already a more compact and easier way doing this.

Comment: see my answer. Hope it meets some of your expectation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for an one-liner using melt, below is an approach (the order desired is kept):

```
# assume DF is your data frame
DF_new = data.frame(trigger = melt(t(DF[,2:3]))[,3], PID = rep(DF[,1], each=2))
DF_new
#    trigger PID
# 1        1   1
# 2        5   1
# 3        2   1
# 4        5   1
# 5        3   1
# 6        5   1
# 7        1   2
# 8        5   2
# 9        2   2
# 10       5   2
# 11       3   2
# 12       5   2
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest would be to use `melt`.  This is the same as your initial dataframe (`d1`) unless the exact order of trigger is important.

```
library(reshape2)
d2 <- melt(d, id="PID", value.name="trigger")[,c(3,1)]
> d2
       trigger PID
1        1   1
2        2   1
3        3   1
4        1   2
5        2   2
6        3   2
7        5   1
8        5   1
9        5   1
10       5   2
11       5   2
12       5   2
```

If you are fond of using `base` functions you can also use `reshape`

```
d3 <- reshape(d, direction="long", 
              varying=list(names(d)[2:3]), 
              v.names="trigger",
              idvar="PID", 
              new.row.names=seq(12))[,c(3,1)]
```

You can see they are both identical by ordering by trigger

```
> d2[order(d2$trigger),]
   trigger PID
1        1   1
4        1   2
2        2   1
5        2   2
3        3   1
6        3   2
7        5   1
8        5   1
9        5   1
10       5   2
11       5   2
12       5   2
> d1[order(d1$trigger),]
   trigger PID
1        1   1
7        1   2
3        2   1
9        2   2
5        3   1
11       3   2
2        5   1
4        5   1
6        5   1
8        5   2
10       5   2
12       5   2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is almost what I wanted and maybe I explained it vague, so I try to correct myself. Being more specific, the exact order of the rows is important. The new, long column in d1 (d1$trigger) should start with d[1,2] then d[1,3], followed by d[2,2], d[2,3], d[3,2], d[3,3], d[4,2],d[4,3], d[5,2], d[5,3], d[6,2] and d[6,3]...So at the end, I will have all the triggers for PID 1, and PID 2 separately. In your solution, PID is alternating. If I use  d3[order(d3$PID),], then the order of the triggers will be lost.

Comment: Why is it so important to maintain that exact order?  The data is identical. What are you trying to do that is so restrictive?

Comment: I wan to compare the triggers I sent with the triggers I received to ensure that it was correctly sent/interpreted.

Comment: Couldn't you just sort the 'sent' triggers as well and then compare?  Perhaps it would be best if you could provide a full example of this comparison and where it currently fails.

Comment: then it is easier if I use the code above, what I wrote during my question. I can transpose the df and create a vector and simply compare the values.I thought there is a clean-cut solution for such kind of reshaping procedures.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "elegance" is subjective, but if you are looking for an alternative, you can consider `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. In order for `merged.stack` to work correctly, though, your ID variables need to be unique. For this, you can use `getanID` (also from "splitstackshape"):

```
library(splitstackshape)
packageVersion("splitstackshape")
# [1] ‘1.4.2’
merged.stack(getanID(d, "PID"), var.stubs = "Cue", 
             sep = "var.stubs")[, c("PID", "Cue"), with = FALSE]
#     PID Cue
#  1:   1   1
#  2:   1   5
#  3:   1   2
#  4:   1   5
#  5:   1   3
#  6:   1   5
#  7:   2   1
#  8:   2   5
#  9:   2   2
# 10:   2   5
# 11:   2   3
# 12:   2   5

## factor levels retained as desired
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  12 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ PID: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ Cue: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","5": 1 4 2 4 3 4 1 4 2 4 ...
#  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "PID"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

By default, this approach would create a few extra columns if you simply did:

```
merged.stack(getanID(d, "PID"), var.stubs = "Cue", sep = "var.stubs")
```

The two extra columns would be:

- `.id`, created by `getanID`. This column, when combined with the "PID" column would create unique IDs.
- `.time_1`, which is the result of the "stacking" step to indicate which "Cue" column the value came from (in this case, cycling between 1 and 2 to represent "Cue1" and "Cue2").

The part of the code that reads `[, c("PID", "Cue"), with = FALSE]` means to just show us those two columns (since that's all you seem to be interested in).

Comment: Thanks @Arun for bringing this question [to my attention](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/issues/37).